# ElasticSearch ports in iptables

Tags: iptables, elasticsearch

I have setup an elastic-search cluster with two data nodes, one master node and one client node with `kibana`. I was running it with `iptables` disabled on each node.

Now I need to enable `iptables` and I want to know which of the ports (9200 , 9300) I need to open on each node and in which direction (incoming or outgoing or both).

I also need to know on which node i need to place authentication , only the client node?

Comment: What version of Linux are you running?

Comment: It is `CentOS 6`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elasticsearch uses the following port ranges:

- 9200-9300: Web API connectivity.
- 9300-9400: Infra / Node communication

Between Elasticsearch Cluster nodes:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <source> --dport 9300:9400 -j ACCEPT
```

Between Master and Kibana (client > server):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <source> --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
```

Elasticsearch uses by default UDP multicast to discover other nodes on the network to form a cluster. you can use the following rule to enable that

```
iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
```

OR

Alternatively and a better option (larger clusters benefit more from this) is to [minimize chatter from multicast by switching to unicast](http://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/highly-available-elk-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-unicast-mode) (note some cloud providers do not allow unicast)

Alternatively, you can also define your own configuration for port binding using [Transport](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html).

```
transport.profiles.default.port: 9300-9400
transport.profiles.default.bind_host: 10.0.0.1
transport.profiles.client.port: 9500-9600
transport.profiles.client.bind_host: 192.168.0.1
transport.profiles.dmz.port: 9700-9800
transport.profiles.dmz.bind_host: 172.16.1.2
```